# setValue() not work corectly in combobox with pagination sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

I have combobox with pagination inside:

```
var itemsSelect = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    id           : 'itemsControllerSelect',
    emptyText    : 'not found',
    pageSize: true,
    store        : {
        type    : 'store',
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 4,
        proxy   : {
            type: 'api',
            url : SITE_URL + '/api/items'
        }
    },
    triggerAction: 'all',
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField   : 'id'
});
```

When I set value for edit using `Ext.getCmp('itemsControllerSelect').setValue(5);`
Inside combo displayed id item, but I want to display name.
If I set value using id witch is on first page all work corecctly.

I think the problem is that I do not have this item in store because item with this id is only second page in pagination.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to set the combo box to a value that is not displayed from the store? You have not set the remoteSort property either. 

Senchas documentation on setValue() is quite clear in the value has to be in the store before it will work properly. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#method-setValue. A fiddle would allow us to help more so we can understand the number of records/pages in the store.

Comment: After expand combo store load 15 records with ids 1-15, but when I wont to set value for combo with id 20 my text value for this id not displayed in combo, because next store with that value not loaded.
I wont to do it that set current value in combo on edit form.

Comment: Then you will need to make sure the record with id=20 is loaded before setting the value. Clearly you cannot set a value that is not there and expect it to trigger loading the next set of records unless you specifically code the event to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, but now I solved that problem using next way:
when open modal for edit I load one row and dynamically add into combo and my combo displayed value correctly.
But some time in combo displayed only id